# Determine function has defined as a expression or declaried as function

Tags: javascript

I want to know how the function has been initialized, with the expression or declaried as fuction. _ Amazon interview question

```
expression : var a = function (){ }
declaration: function a (){ }
```

Comment: what the difference? why you think you need this? it seems like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to ask?

Comment: if you sure that in expression used only anonymous function you can check [`name` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name).

Comment: It was an interview question, just I want to know the answer. I know it does not make any differences.

Comment: so in general it is not possible, but in some special cases you can check [`name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only way, we can determine function has defined with function declarations not as expression.

as Grundy mentioned `name` property of the respective function gives require information, if it has been defined with expression `name` property holds `undefined` value, else it holds function name.

Here is the code :

```
var isDefinedAsFunction = function(fn){
    return fn.name !== undefined
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just do a.toString() and parse out the name. Or do the same with regular expressions

```
a.toString().test(/^\s*function\s*\(/);
```

```
function a(){ };  // gives false
var a = function (){ };   // gives true
```

---

Of course as Grundy pointed out this fails with named functions. Something like

```
var a = function b() {};
```

or

```
function b() {};
var a = b;
```

---

And ES6 has `.name` (see the Browser table at the bottom for the current state of affairs) - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name

Comment: what if expression is: `var a = function funcName(){ }`?

Comment: Updated that caveat in the answer. Thanks! But I guess OP was looking to distinguish named function expression and declarations from anonymous function expressions.

Comment: seems you right, because OP say that this interview question :-), also you can add to answer that in ES6 provided [name property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name), so, not neen it regex

Comment: Thanks again! edited that in. I was trying that initially but realized IE11 doesn't support that yet (chrome does)

Comment: i see that any IE not realized that :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to do so. The only difference between:

```
var func = function(){ };
```

and:

```
function func() { };
```

Is that the first one gets assigned on runtime. The way I see it, is that both function statements return a reference to their respective function objects. In that sense they are both the same. The only thing you could argue is that one is not named and the other one is, but you could have assigned a named function to a variable too.

However, there seems to be a difference on how they get assigned. The second one seems to get assigned to a variable that its named after, right at the start of the execution context. The first one has to wait for the explicit assignment within the execution context.

So you'd be testing for when they get assigned. You might think that's is possible to do so within the global object like:

```js
//some protected vars that can't work without same-origin
var protected = ['caches', 'localStorage', 'sessionStorage', 'frameElement'];
var definedAtInit = [];
    for(prop in window){
        if(!isSandboxed(prop) && typeof window[prop] === 'function'){
           definedAtInit.push(prop);
        }
    };

    function isSandboxed(prop){
      return protected.indexOf(prop) !== -1;
    }

    function isItDefinedAtInit(funcName){
       return definedAtInit.indexOf(funcName) !== -1;
    }

    var func = function() {
       console.log('test');
    }

    var results = { isItDefinedAtInit : isItDefinedAtInit('isItDefinedAtInit'),
                   func : isItDefinedAtInit('func')
                   };

    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(results, '/t');
```

```html
<pre id="results"></pre>
```

However, you could still do something like:

```
var isItDefinedAtInit = function() { };
//After this, isItDefinedAtInit('isItDefinedAtInit') would be wrong.
```

And you still have the problems with other execution contexts, I don't think functions declared within a function execution context get attached to any object.

I think these kind of checks are a bad idea to be honest.